# No pg_hba.conf while trying to use node-postgres

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to use node-postgres, but I keep getting an error when I try to connect.  Here's the terminal output:

```
.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287
        const message = name === 'notice' ? new messages_1.NoticeMessage(length, messageValue) : new messages_1.DatabaseError(messageValue, length, name);
                                                                                                 ^

error: Ident authentication failed for user "user-name"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 94,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '305',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}
```

From other questions I've found, it looks like I need to add this line to pg_hba.conf:
`local    all    all    md5`

Unfortunately, I don't have such a file.  I did find pg_hba.conf.sample, which I copy-pasted into pg_hba.conf (in the local directory where I'm editing my js code).  I added the line, but this hasn't changed any behavior.

Throughout all of this, I have been able to log into the database via the terminal using `$ psql database-name` without problem.

Comment: pg_hba.conf is a *server* configuration file, not a client file.  Unless you are the dba, you probably don't have access to it.  You would need to talk to whoever is in charge of your database server.

Comment: @jjanes  I am the administrator, though I'm not a good one.

Comment: @jjanes Thinking on your comment made me realize should search as root, which I did, and I figured out the answer from there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I wasn't searching for the pg_hba.conf as root.  I found and edited it by using sudo:

```
$ sudo locate pg_hba.conf
/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
$ sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

I changed the file to switch everything to use the md5 method:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

After this change, there's no more error!